# How can I add brands and flavors in navigation menu with categories?

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3, navigation, topmenu

I want to show categories of items also want to show the brands and flavors of item according to the parent it has.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Store -> Attributes -> Products**
2. Open your required attribute
3. Open **Storefront Properties**  tab
4. Select **"Yes"** in **Use in Layered Navigation** option.
5. Run indexing

This should display your attribute on product list filters

Comment: It's already filterable(with results) option selected and brands are showing in filter 
but i want to add brands in top menu navigation to easily separate categories using brands and flavors